# I need to sort an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting json data like this

```
[
  {

    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "fffda276-c7ed-4931-8211-48b3ae304b6f",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "db9dd205-5986-432f-9aaf-1079d6fdd28c",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "5ae8991c-bbcd-4a97-a5ad-b1aac6d765c0",
        "size": "",
      },
      {
        "id": "f670609a-d200-4c03-a8a7-34e2b244a4c7",
        "size": "Small",
      }
    ],
    "id": "95a9c2eb-7dac-45d6-9a6a-2718859d91f3",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "77f5b953-772a-4e02-834f-6d7eb4236223",
        "size": "Medium",
      },
      {
        "id": "04e909bc-0087-479d-9f4d-8f4ad03f8dd0",
        "size": "Large",
      },
      {
        "id": "4a628027-3ec8-450c-943e-7dce96f0bbb4",
        "size": "Small",
      },
      {
        "id": "7c5c638b-bab6-4a10-ba3e-ebdc8939021d",
        "size": "Large",
      }
    ],
    "id": "bc38b226-78cd-4928-80a0-589a9da2cd40",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "e6011db7-0662-4b52-9d26-e6be07226826",
        "size": "Large",
      },
      {
        "id": "ad678447-3e18-4537-baa1-b762dc03f6cd",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "e1c59ebd-b567-462f-ac00-068ff7938055",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "3525d215-e9eb-4417-8b35-902936181d29",
        "size": "Medium",
      },
      {
        "id": "4c023985-a3c0-4783-a9c3-d51a21bf63d9",
        "size": "Large",
      },
      {
        "id": "7ef8d908-8a29-4d40-bdfe-121895d01ebc",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "d9e88ddc-1b7e-4a68-b087-46d365f266a3",
  }
]
```

I need to reorder entire data based on emission array's size like large, medium and small, so that first array must be no of count of Large, then medium and small, it needs to be sorted

Note: some data can also be without size those data can be omitted, but still needs to be present in final sorted array

Output:

```js
[
  
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "77f5b953-772a-4e02-834f-6d7eb4236223",
        "size": "Medium",
      },
      {
        "id": "04e909bc-0087-479d-9f4d-8f4ad03f8dd0",
        "size": "Large",
      },
      {
        "id": "4a628027-3ec8-450c-943e-7dce96f0bbb4",
        "size": "Small",
      },
      {
        "id": "7c5c638b-bab6-4a10-ba3e-ebdc8939021d",
        "size": "Large",
      }
    ],
    "id": "bc38b226-78cd-4928-80a0-589a9da2cd40",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "3525d215-e9eb-4417-8b35-902936181d29",
        "size": "Medium",
      },
      {
        "id": "4c023985-a3c0-4783-a9c3-d51a21bf63d9",
        "size": "Large",
      },
      {
        "id": "7ef8d908-8a29-4d40-bdfe-121895d01ebc",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "d9e88ddc-1b7e-4a68-b087-46d365f266a3",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "e6011db7-0662-4b52-9d26-e6be07226826",
        "size": "Large",
      },
      {
        "id": "ad678447-3e18-4537-baa1-b762dc03f6cd",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "e1c59ebd-b567-462f-ac00-068ff7938055",
  },
  {

    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "fffda276-c7ed-4931-8211-48b3ae304b6f",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "db9dd205-5986-432f-9aaf-1079d6fdd28c",
  },
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "5ae8991c-bbcd-4a97-a5ad-b1aac6d765c0",
        "size": "",
      },
      {
        "id": "f670609a-d200-4c03-a8a7-34e2b244a4c7",
        "size": "Small",
      }
    ],
    "id": "95a9c2eb-7dac-45d6-9a6a-2718859d91f3",
  }
]
```

Comment: Would be good to see an example of the expected output, please?

Comment: ^^ and try possibly.

Comment: From your question is unclear what the output shoud be.

Comment: @all I have updated expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count wanted type and sort descending.

```js
const
    count = ({ emission }, type) =>
        emission.reduce((r, { size }) => r + (type === size), 0),
    data = [{ emission: [{ id: "fffda276-c7ed-4931-8211-48b3ae304b6f", size: "Medium" }], id: "db9dd205-5986-432f-9aaf-1079d6fdd28c" }, { emission: [{ id: "5ae8991c-bbcd-4a97-a5ad-b1aac6d765c0", size: "" }, { id: "f670609a-d200-4c03-a8a7-34e2b244a4c7", size: "Small" }], id: "95a9c2eb-7dac-45d6-9a6a-2718859d91f3" }, { emission: [{ id: "77f5b953-772a-4e02-834f-6d7eb4236223", size: "Medium" }, { id: "04e909bc-0087-479d-9f4d-8f4ad03f8dd0", size: "Large" }, { id: "4a628027-3ec8-450c-943e-7dce96f0bbb4", size: "Small" }, { id: "7c5c638b-bab6-4a10-ba3e-ebdc8939021d", size: "Large" }], id: "bc38b226-78cd-4928-80a0-589a9da2cd40" }, { emission: [{ id: "e6011db7-0662-4b52-9d26-e6be07226826", size: "Large" }, { id: "ad678447-3e18-4537-baa1-b762dc03f6cd", size: "Medium" }], id: "e1c59ebd-b567-462f-ac00-068ff7938055" }, { emission: [{ id: "3525d215-e9eb-4417-8b35-902936181d29", size: "Medium" }, { id: "4c023985-a3c0-4783-a9c3-d51a21bf63d9", size: "Large" }, { id: "7ef8d908-8a29-4d40-bdfe-121895d01ebc", size: "Medium" }], id: "d9e88ddc-1b7e-4a68-b087-46d365f266a3" }];

data.sort((a, b) => 
    count(b, 'Large') - count(a, 'Large') ||
    count(b, 'Medium') - count(a, 'Medium') ||
    count(b, 'Small') - count(a, 'Small')
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fully understand what you meant, but I assume a sorting by `Large`, `Medium` and `Small` might help you

```js
let data = [
  {
    "emission": [
      {
        "id": "fffda276-c7ed-4931-8211-48b3ae304b6f",
        "size": "Medium",
      }
    ],
    "id": "db9dd205-5986-432f-9aaf-1079d6fdd28c",
  },
  // ... other data objects
];

let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
  let aCount = countSizes(a.emission, 'Large');
  let bCount = countSizes(b.emission, 'Large');
  if (aCount !== bCount) {
    return bCount - aCount;
  }
  aCount = countSizes(a.emission, 'Medium');
  bCount = countSizes(b.emission, 'Medium');
  if (aCount !== bCount) {
    return bCount - aCount;
  }
  aCount = countSizes(a.emission, 'Small');
  bCount = countSizes(b.emission, 'Small');
  return bCount - aCount;
});

function countSizes(emission, size) {
  return emission.filter(e => e.size === size).length;
}

console.log(sortedData);
```

Explanation:

In the code, the `countSizes` function is used to count the number of occurrences of a specific size in the `emission` array. The sort method is used to sort the data array based on the number of occurrences of `Large`, `Medium`, and `Small` sizes, in that order. The resulting `sortedData` array will have the data objects ordered based on the number of occurrences of the sizes in the `emission` array.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]' Getting error

Comment: @MonishJerin are you sure you're using correctly? `data` in my answer should be the actual data you're providing in your question.

Comment: Yes the format i have updated is correct

Comment: What do you mean? The first JSON object in your question should be the `data` variable in my answer. It doesn't throw an error. Pls double check.

Comment: @MonishJerin No problem, glad it worked. Can you please upvote my answer and accept as an answer, please?